# Find number of ones in from 0 to n recursively

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, recursion

I have to make a recursive function that finds the number of ones from 0 to n recursively.

So f(16) = 9

(1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

This is obviously homework so I would appreciated if you did NOT post any code, just the reasoning behind it.

What I've reasoned so far is that if you do %10 of a number it will tell you if the least significant is a one, also if you do an integer division by 10 you lose that digit.

So I'm guessing the approach will be can be checking `if number%10 == 1` and then calling the function with f(n/10), but then I get lost in the actual implementation.

I would appreciate if you could comment what approach would you use, it has to be recursive just because it's home work, the procedural approach was trivial.

Comment: Your approach sounds right. What do you do if there are no more digits to process?

Comment: You just described the approach pretty much as well as anybody. So you're stuck on the implementation? Could you show a vague example of the code you tried, and we can point out the problem?

Comment: @honk I guess you would go to f(number-1)

Comment: @minitech will post in a sec some pseudo code

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) challenge.  Your approach should work, in terms of providing an iterative/O(n) solution.  However with these kinds of problems it is often the case that a more efficient solution exists, based upon recognizing and exploiting patterns in the data.

Comment: @aroth or it the OP has tagged it with `homework` and `recursion`, it could be homework to help them learn about recursion...

Comment: @aroth it is exactly as jon says, its only purpose it practice recursion, and it is homework, though I agree, very similar to the PE challenges in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two parts to your problem.

1. Find numbers of ones in number.
2. Find numbers of ones in all the numbers less than it (but more than zero).

Part one first:

If the right-most digit is 1, then `number % 10 == 1`.
If the number is > 9 you need to check other digits, you can do this by doing the same test on the number after integer-divide 10. If the number <= 9, then that would give you zero.

So your OnesInNumber function is a bit like:

1. If number == 0, return 0.
2. Otherwise call OnesInNumber on `number / 10`.
3. If `number % 10 == 1` add 1 to that result.
4. Return the result.

This will for example, give you `1` when called on `10`, `1`, `12`, `303212`, give you `2` when called on `11`, and so on.

Your OnesInZeroUntil function is then like:

1. If number <= 0, return 0.
2. Otherwise call OnesInZeroUntil on `number - 1`.
3. Add `OnesInNumber(number)` to this.
4. Return the result.

So you've a recursive function that works out the number of `1` in a number, and another recursive function that works out the number of `1` in every number up to that one, building on that first function.

That'd be enough to write a quick 2 functions in, had you not requested that we don't.

(Tip: If your teacher isn't already requiring it, see if you can work out how to do this without recursion. Every recursive function can be re-written as a non-recursive form, and it's a practical skill to be able to do that some people teaching recursion don't seem to cover).

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I need, I'll give it a try! I did write the non-recursive form in 2 minutes, I sometimes get stuck in silly problems when I have to something recursive. Thanks

Comment: Ah, then you need to ignore that tip entirely until you're "thinking recursively". Once you get your eureka moment recursion stops being something to figure out and just "how to do it". The tip comes in after that. Programming is all about switching mental abstraction levels (Dijkstra pointed out we do so over greater magnitudes than people going from particle physics up to galaxies), and mentally switching iteration <-> recursion in both ways is a similar skill.

Comment: Nice advice, I'm getting better but I'm still trying to think it iteratively. Anyway, solved the damn thing :) I will keep practising!! Thank you!

Comment: Look for recursion everywhere, like Calvin and Hobbes looking for treasure in their garden! There'll come a Eureka when you realise it can be applied to all sorts of things... Then comes the time to stop and just use it when it comes naturally, possibly even taking it out later as an optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

For these types of problems, I find it helps to write some sort of diagram showing the patterns. For instance, if you count by tens, you know that the first set (0-9) contains one 1.

(0-9)     -- 1
(10-19)   -- 11
(21-29)   -- 1
  | |     -- 1
(100-109) -- 11
(110-119) -- 21
(120-129) -- 11
  | |     -- 11
(200-209) -- 1
(210-219) -- 11
(220-229) -- 1
  | |     -- 1
...
(1000-1009) etc...

It may take a while, but this will help you find patterns so you can come up with a more sytematic answer. I don't want to give you *too* much help since it's a homework problem, but that's the approach I take when I'm solving creative math problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right in your approach. For every number you want a function that will return the "number of ones" in the decimal representation. A recursive representation of this (note you could also do this iteratively).

Like all recursive functions, you need your end-state catch, i.e., if the input = 0 return 0. Besides that (without giving it all away) you just need to add your current result to the sub-result:

```
 if number==0
     return 0
 if number%10==1
     return myFunc(number/10) + 1
 else
     return myFunc(number/10)
```

However, as I said before, there is no need to use recursion. An iterative solution is probably better here since the function is linear with respect to the number of digits.

Comment: Didn't the OP say: *This is obviously homework so I would appreciated if you did NOT post any code, just the reasoning behind it.*

Comment: @Blender yeah well, but at least I had figured that much out, my main problem is to combine that part doing it from n to 0.